Tangential connection is well-defined
I'm struggling with the problem 4-1 of introduction to Riemannian manifolds by J. M. Lee.
I'm no idea I can come up with something.

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an embedded submanifold and $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. For every point $p \in M$ and vector $v \in T_pM$, define $\nabla_v Y$ by $\pi^T(\bar{\nabla}_v \tilde{Y}$) with $\tilde{Y}$ an extension of $Y$ on a open subset containing $M$ and $\pi^T$ the tangential projection. Prove it is independent on the choice of extension $\tilde{Y}$ of $Y$.

My try.
Let $p \in M$ and two extensions of $Y$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ on a open subset containing $M$. Because $M$ is a embedded submanifold, exists a chart $\varphi_p : U_p \rightarrow V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ that $\varphi_p(U_p \cap M ) = \{x^{k+1}  = \ldots = x^m = 0\} $. Thus $T_pM = \langle{\partial_1|_p,\ldots, \partial_k|_p}\rangle$, and
$$
\nabla_{v}^{T}Y|_p = \pi^T(\bar{\nabla}_{v}Y_1)|_p= \sum_{i = 1}^n v(Y_1^i)\pi_p^T(\partial_i|_p ) = \sum_{i = 1}^k v(Y_1^i)\partial_i|_p
$$
If it is true that $v(Y_1^i) = v(Y^i) = v(Y_2^i)$, then we finished, but I can't prove it. Any help?

Let $\bar{\nabla}$ be the connection on $T\mathbb{R}^n$ defined as following:
$$\bar{\nabla}_XY= \sum_{i=1}^n X(Y^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \tag{1}$$
Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an embedded submanifold, let $p \in M$, $v \in T_pM$ and $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. We define:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_v^{T}Y = \pi^T(\bar{\nabla}_{\tilde{v}} \widetilde{Y})\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\pi^T: T\mathbb{R}^n\rvert_{M} \to TM$ is the tangential projection, $\widetilde{Y} \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ an arbitrary extencion of $Y$, $\tilde{v}=d_pi(v)$ with $i:M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ the inclusion.
So we want prove the following:

Lemma: The definition (2) does not depend from the choice of the particular extencion of $Y$

To me the key point is that $\bar{\nabla}$, as a connection, is a local operator. In particular $\bar{\nabla}_{\tilde{v}} \widetilde{Y} = \bar{\nabla}_{X}Y(p)$ where $X, Y \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $X_p=\tilde{v}$ and $Y$ agree with $\widetilde{Y}$ in some neighborhood of $p$.
If you want something more explicit we can retrace what is in fact the proof of locality of $\bar{\nabla}$. Since $\bar{\nabla}_{\tilde{v}}(.)$ and $\pi^T(p, .)$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linear, to prove the statement of the lemma is sufficient to show that if $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is vanishing in $M$ then $\pi^T(\bar{\nabla}_{\tilde{v}} Y)=0$. Now we observe:
$$\tilde{v}(Y^j)=\sum_{i=1}^n\tilde{v}^i\frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}\bigg{|}_p$$
But since the support of the derivative is contained in the support of the function, we have $\frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}\big{|}_p=0$, then $\tilde{v}(Y^j)=0, \forall j$. Then from (1) we conclude $\bar{\nabla}_{\tilde{v}} Y=0$ and at the end, since the linearity, $\pi^T(\bar{\nabla}_{\tilde{v}} Y)=0$. $\square$
